# How to grant the proper access to vscode so that when I run c++ code it doesn't ask for document access every time?

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code

[image]
Every time when I run c or c++ code, I have to grant the access of executable file to its location, is there a way of preventing this operation by granting vscode some type of access?

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be:
install codelldb and setting `"type": "lldb"` in launch.json.